# Filter and combine values of two dataframe with different shape

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

df1.columns

`['Name' 'Age' 'Sex' 'Date Of Birth' 'Location' 'Roll No' 'Height']`

df1.shape

`#rows, columns`

`(200,7)`

df2.columns

`['Name' 'Country' 'Home Town' 'Father's Name' 'Mother's Name' 'Mother Tongue' 'Weight' 'Grade' 'Roll No' '10' '15' '110' '170']`

df2.shape

`#rows, columns`

`(240,13)`

I want to combined df1 and df2
Based on condition:

```
(df1['Roll No']==df2['Roll No']) and ((df2['10'] < df1['Age'] < df2['12']) and (df2['110']  < df1['Height'] < df2['170']))
```

Combined df4

`['Name' 'Age' 'Sex' 'Date Of Birth' 'Location' 'Roll No' 'Height' 'Name' 'Country' 'Home Town' 'Father's Name' 'Mother's Name' 'Mother Tongue' 'Weight' 'Grade' 'Roll No' '10' '15' '110' '170']`

If we could remove duplicate rows `Name` `Roll No` it would be efficient

How to combine `isin` and `query` to achieve this?

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: include some data for the dataframes and also the expected output so we can replicate the question

Answer (score 0):

I prepared somewhat limited version of your data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ 3, 4, 5, 1],
    [ 3, 7, 4, 2]],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'F'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ 3, 3,  7, 4, 8, 1],
    [ 3, 5,  9, 4, 8, 1],
    [ 3, 5,  9, 3, 5, 2],
    [ 3, 6, 11, 5, 9, 2]],
    columns=['A', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'F'])
```

I dropped *E* column from *df1* and *['G', 'L', 'M', 'N']* columns
from *df2* (they are not essential to the solution).

To perform the first part of your task - merge on *F* column, we
can run:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.drop(columns=['A']), on=['F'])
```

*F* column is eliminated automatically by *merge* as the join criterion.
*A* column I dropped explicitely, because otherwise the output
would have contained *A_x* and *A_y* columns.

If you guarantee that *A* columns in both DataFrames are equal (*df1.A == df2.A*),
for rows to merge, you can also write:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2), on=['A', 'F'])
```

or even shorter:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2))
```

because the default merge criterion are all common columns.

Note that the default merge mode (*how*) is **inner**. If you want another
possible merge mode, you should specify it explicitely.

The second part can be performed with *query* method:

```
df3.query('H < B and B < I and J < C and C < K')
```

Note that now all columns are in a **single** DataFrame, so we can
use just column names.

For my test data, the result is:

```
   A  B  C  F  H  I  J  K
0  3  4  5  1  3  7  4  8
2  3  7  4  2  5  9  3  5
```

Alternative: You can do the whole task with a single instruction, not using
any intemediate DataFrame:

```
df1.merge(df2.drop(columns=['A'])).query('H < B and B < I and J < C and C < K')
```

Another alternative: The *query* condition can be even shorter:

```
'H < B < I and J < C < K'
```